# How Can I See Pageviews Per Post - Google Analytics & WordPress

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

### Background

I just moved my blog over from Blogger to WordPress, and I'm trying to replicate the stats reporting that I had before. I've got Google Analytics integrated with my website, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to see the data I'm looking for.

What I want is to be able to see a list of all my posts, with the number of page views: today, this week, this month, and forever. Similar to this:

[image]

### Question

Is it possible to set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look under Behavior > Site Content > All Pages

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for never marking this as the answer. Though now that I've learned more about Google Analytics, we should probably add here something about the daterange. Do you mind if I edit this answer to provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Jetpack plugin on WordPress, it's a very good plugin to see pageviews per day/week/month.

If you want check pageviews on Google Analytics too, you can try with Google Analytics by Monster Analytics (formerly Yoast), check it here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

( For people searching for same thing and came here, as It is too late to answer  )
In PHP you can do something like :-

```
 return $analytics->data_ga->get(
          'ga:' . $profileId,
          $start_date,
          $end_date,
          'ga:pageviews',


          array('dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle');
```

for more idea on it you can visit :-[How to use refresh token to get authorized in background and getting access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089788/google-analytics-api-pagination-current-page-number-and-nextpage-authentication)

And there are 2/3 more posts related to it, I have developed an google analytics plugin for my own use , so you can do something like it.There are some free plugin   available you can use them and get the result on your wordpress dashboard.

I got [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869513/google-analytics-php-api-gapi-getting-number-of-page-views?rq=1) just now, you can also see it